# will normalization of school database make better perfomance

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, normalization

I have old server and huge MySQL database of students marks
There is only one common table for all students:

> student_id | teacher_id | mark | comment

There are six schools in this project and ~800 of students, everyday we have ~5000 of marks

Students have problem with perfomance - every query of their marks takes about two minutes to get results
by the way I use table indexing

I have the question - if I use normalization and make separate table for every student like this:

## STUDENTS_TABLE

```
student_id | table
ivanov     | ivanov_table
```

## IVANOV_TABLE

```
teacher_id | mark | comment
```

will it help me make better perfomance?

I have no oportunity to buy new server.

ADD:
when I use `mysql> SELECT * FROM all_students_table where student_id=001` it takes to long. I think it is because of information of all students is in one huge table. And I suppose if individual table for every student will be created - it will take less time for query like this: `mysql> SELECT * FROM student_001_table`. Am I right?

ADD:
This table is three years old and
`mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM students_marks`

give result 2 453 389 of rows and it grows every day

Comment: You'll need to narrow this down to a particular query and a more specific description of the problem.

Comment: I agree with @tadman, just mention though den-normalized data works better for reporting applications for example

Comment: Making a separate table for each student is not normalizing.  Based on what you have shown us, a date field might help so you can filter on that.

Comment: @TedFilippidis There's warehouse concerns (e.g. [star schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema)) but that's often something you do with a fairly involved transformations and is probably over-kill for this simple case.

Comment: The #1 impediment to slow queries is missing indexes. The second is bad MySQL defaults, either not allocating enough memory to the MySQL server or using the wrong database engine.

Comment: How many rows are we talking here, anyway?  Querying a table and using the student_id seems like it would be quite quick unless there are tens of millions of rows...

Comment: thnx, @tadman: when I use "mysql> SELECT * FROM all_students_table where student_id=001"  it takes to long. I think it is because of information of all students is in one huge table. And I suppose if individual table for every student will be created - it will take less time for query like this: "mysql> SELECT * FROM student_001_table". Am I right?

Comment: Unless your database server is heavily loaded, which you can quickly check using either the MySQL Workbench tool or `SHOW PROCESSLIST`, that should be quick *if* you have the proper indexes. Table scans happen if you don't, and they're **punishingly slow** on large tables.

Comment: How would you do class averages if you did that?

Comment: @bc2946088, This table is three years old and
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM students_marks     give result 2 453 389 of rows and it grows every day

Comment: Show your table DDL (`CREATE TABLE...`) and the results of running `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM all_students_table where student_id=001`. Then `SET profiling = 1`, run your `SELECT...` query again, and post the results of `SHOW profile`.

Comment: @DAN Bracuk, Do you mean how long take a query like this: "mysql> SELECT AVG(marks) FROM students_marks" ?

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the table?

Comment: Also, DO NOT create a table for every student!

Comment: You need to find & read an intro to information modeling & database design Then find & read an intro to database performance/optimization. Please read & act on [mcve]. Many many textbooks are free online.

Answer (score 1):

Since a simple query like `SELECT * FROM all_students_table where student_id=001` takes too long, the only sensible conclusion is that the table does not have proper indexes. A query like this **needs** an index on `student_id`. When that index is present, the query should perform almost as good for 2.5 million rows as it does for 1,000 rows (assuming each `student_id` appears similarly frequently in the table)

Answer (score 0):

First, WHAT @Arjan said about indexes.
Second, from experience, you will need at least 3 tables and probably 5 tables with very precise INDEXes and PRIMARY KEYS

1. Schools
2. Teachers
3. Students
4. Student_In_School
5. Student_Grade (Links Teacher/Student/Grade/Comment) <- Your current table

Third, and this is counter intuitive, performance will DECREASE, because you have to search multiple tables and link them. Normalization is NOT for performance, but rather for sanity checks and validation and elimination of repeated information. For example, you can NOW have the actual names of the teachers/students as opposed to an obscure IDs.

The good news is you have very little data (despite what you think) and an old machine can handle it with proper INDEXes

Hope this helps